# Append a div with a for loop inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, append

Currently I do this in my ajax success call:

```
$(".user_profiles_holder").append('<div class="appendeditems">');
for(var i=0; i<data.userArray.length; i++){
  var user = data.userArray[i];
  $(".appendeditems").append(user.first_name);
}
$(".user_profiles_holder").append('</div>');
```

Is there a better way to do what im doing here? It works... but I imagine it could break depending on how long it takes to loop through the array etc?

Comment: Look for jQuery templating engine like Moustache jTemplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is actually appending 2 divs, as by appending a `</div>` tag you create another `div` - you can only append whole elements at a time. That said, you could optimise the code slightly to create the new element in memory and only make one append to the DOM. Try this:

```
var $appendedItems = $('<div />', { 'class': 'appendeditems' });
for (var i = 0; i < data.userArray.length; i++) {
    $appendedItems.append(data.userArray[i].first_name);
}
$appendedItems.appendTo(".user_profiles_holder");
```